# Handling a "Changeset" in a terraform provider

Tags: go, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have an api that works as follows:

1. Create Changeset using POST `/changeset/`, and get `changeset_id`
2. Create record using `changeset id` using POST `/record/`
3. Create record using `changeset id` using POST `/record/`
4. Create record using `changeset id` using POST `/record/` (etc...)
5. Commit changeset  using POST `/changeset/<id>` with `status: "committed"`. Then all the records in the changeset become "committed".

I'd like to bundle this in my terraform provider, so that I can write something like:

```
resource my-record "1" {...}

resource my-record "2" {...}

resource my-record "3" {...}
```

and have all of the records committed as part of one changeset. Any changes to records within the terraform instance should also follow the logic of:

1. Create changeset
2. change a bunch of records
3. Commit changeset

Is there a way to accomplish this in the `terraform-plugin-sdk` ? Like somehow creating a common context for resources of the same type?

Right now I'm creating and committing a changeset for every record, which is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this setup is currently unsupported in terraform, see related [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/63).

One workaround you can use is to nest these resources into one "meta" resource, so you can create a changeset, add multiple records, and commit it inside one terraform resource. Your config will then look similar to this:

```
resource "myprovider_changeset" "test" {
  record {
    name = "1"
    ...
  }

  record {
    name = "2"
    ...
  }
}
```

Basic idea for implementation would be to have a meta resource with [`schema.TypeSet`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/schemas/schema-types.html#typeset) attributes that define schemas for nested resources and then loop through these sets inside `Create`/`Update`/`Delete` functions.

An example of providers doing the same is [fastly provider service_v1 resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/fastly/fastly/latest/docs/resources/service_v1). You can check how this is implemented: [meta resoruce](https://github.com/fastly/terraform-provider-fastly/blob/main/fastly/base_fastly_service_v1.go), [example of nested resource](https://github.com/fastly/terraform-provider-fastly/blob/main/fastly/block_fastly_service_v1_backend.go).